# Prove that if $2a^2 - b^2 = \pm1$ then $\frac ba \approx \sqrt2$

Tags: approximation

Prove that if $2a^2 - b^2 = \pm1$ then $\frac ba\approx\sqrt2  $

(a,b)
(1,1),(2,3),(5,7),(12,17),(29,41),(70,99)....

Comment: "$\frac ba\approx\sqrt{2}$" is not a formal statement; if you want a proof then you'll need to define what you mean by 'approximately'.  (You should also offer your thoughts on the problem; where it came from, what you've tried, etc.)

Comment: I suggest you read about continued fractions and Pell's equation.

Comment: This is only true for sufficiently small values of $1$. :)

Answer (score 4):

Dividing both sides by $a^2$ and rearranging, we get $$2-\frac{\pm 1}{a^2}=\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2$$
As $a\to \infty$, the left hand side approaches $2$.  Note that $\pm 1$ could be replaced by any integer of small absolute value.  The only reason $\pm 1$ is important is if you want a precise statement about how good $\frac{b}{a}$ is as an approximant to $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$2a^2-b^2=\pm1$$ implies $$2a^2=b^2\pm1$$ or $$\frac{b^2\pm1}{a^2}=\frac{b^2}{a^2}\pm\frac{1}{a^2}=2$$

So, we have $$\frac{b^2}{a^2}=2\pm \frac{1}{a^2}\approx 2$$

Therefore we have $\frac{b}{a}\approx \sqrt{2}$